# Function Differentiability, definability, where $f'(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus

I get confused around whether to include $a$ and $b$ in only when it comes to decide if it s strictly increasing let say.

Let us say f is defined on $[a, b]$, and f is derivable at a, and $f'(x) > 0$ on $]a,b]$ such that $f'(a) = 0$, we say $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

Let us suppose $f$ is not derivable at $a$, and $a$ is in the domain of definition  of $f$, and $f'(x) > 0$ on $]a, b]$, we say that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

Let s have a simple functions here: $f(x) = (x-1)\sqrt{x}$

Why you have to conclude as in textbooks that f is strictly increasing on $]\frac{1}{3}, +\infty[$ and strictly decreasing on $[0, \frac{1}{3}[$.

In other words, when we have $f'(x) > 0$ on $(a, b)$, when do we include or not include $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The proper term is "differentiable" instead of "derivable."

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say why someone else did or did not do something. What I know is this: if $f\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is continuous and if it differentiable on $(a,b)$ with $f'(x)>0$ for each $\in(a,b)$, then $f$ is strictly increasing in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks, that s what I know. Take this f(x) = (x-1)sqrt(x), you can apply all of the above, but yet to find as I have in textbooks, it s strictly increasing on ]1\3, +00[ and strictly decreasing on [0, 1/3[, according to the definition above 1/3 should be in not out.

Comment: Jose, if you can comment on the below discussion. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing for me to comment. I think that what egreg wrote is clear and sensible.

Comment: If you could visit his last comment trying to understand the same as I am. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to know whether $f$ is differentiable at the extremes of the interval, because the mean value theorem holds nonetheless, provided, of course, that $f$ is differentiable over $(a,b)$. It *may* be differentiable or not at $a$ or $b$, but this is immaterial.

If $a\le x< y\le b$, the mean value theorem says
$$
\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=f'(c)
$$
where $x<c<y$. Since $f'(c)$ is defined and positive, you get that $f$ is increasing over $[a,b]$.

For the same reason, if $f$ is continuous and differentiable over $(a,b)$ and $f'(x)>0$ for every $x\in(a,b)$ *except* at a point $c\in(a,b)$ where the derivative might even not exist (a common case is when $f'(c)=0$), then $f$ is globally increasing over $(a,b)$. We only need to see that if $a<x<c<y<b$, then $f(x)<f(y)$ (for the other situations we already know). By the statement above, $f(x)<f(c)<f(y)$.

The book is not wrong in the case you cite: the function is indeed strictly increasing over $(-1/3,\infty)$, but it is also strictly increasing over $[-1/3,\infty)$ and, similarly, strictly decreasing over $[0,1/3)$, but *also* over $[0,1/3]$.

Students are often confused about this and possibly this is the reason why the book excludes $1/3$ from the intervals. There's no contradiction in the function being decreasing over $[a,b]$ and decreasing over $[b,c]$: this just means $b$ is a local minimum.

Comment: I do really know all of the theory, and by what you have said, why 1/3 is not included. If I don t have to care, then on exam I need to know. Thanks

Comment: @J.Moh I added some comments. If your instructors want like the book says, do as they want. :-) But be certain that you're right nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks, but notice it didn t say it is strictly increasing over (1/3, 00) and strictly increasing over [1\3, 00[. It says it s str incr over ]1\3, 00[, pretty direct, that we have f'(1/3) =0

Comment: @J.Moh Sorry, but wasn't the question about including the extremes of the interval?

Comment: Yes. You can refer back to the function and see.

Comment: I mean I just don t get why 1/3 is not included. In many other examples, such c would be included. For example, take f(x) = (2x +1)^4 => f'(x) = 8(2x +1)^3 and f'(-1/2) = 0 => f is strictly increasing over [-1/2, +00[ and str decr over ]-00, -1/2]

Comment: I tried to give you examples from the book and their formal solutions.

Comment: @J.Moh I *don't* know why they don't include the extreme. I tried to explain a possible reason. In my opinion they *should* include them.

Comment: Me too, I just can t find anything about that, tried to think of any special place f holds for 1/3, I could not, maybe the professor does haha

Comment: Not just that, many other examples, they go between including and not including and offering no explanation.

Comment: @J.Moh Maybe the book has several authors? :-)

Comment: No, a standard problem based book in calculus, in Morocco, following the french system of course.